# Looking for a very gentle first book on Measure Theoretic probability

Tags: measure-theory, book-recommendation

I am looking for a *very gentle first book* on **measure theory**. I want to acquaint myself with the basic ideas in Measure theory. Briefly, my background is as follows.

I am self-learning basic probability theory through a couple of books:

- Introduction to Probability theory and its applications, Volume I - William Feller. (Currently reading Chapter X. Law of Large Numbers).
- Probability and Random Processes - Grimmett and Stirzaker (Currently studying Chapter II. Random variables and distribution functions).

I am also learning Real Analysis (at the level of Baby Rudin) through the book:

- Understanding Analysis, Stephen Abbott. (Currently reading chapter II on sequences and series).

One of the books I have in mind, is Sheldon Axler's book on measure theory (it's modern). Do you think I can jump into it anyway, given my current background? Also, any video playlists(lectures) are welcome.

Comment: By the way, the book by Feller that you’re learning from is excellent

Comment: With your current background in real analysis Axler’s text is definitely out of scope.

Comment: @ChubbyChef, thanks, may I ask, will there a be big leap once I manage to work through Abbott's book on analysis, to go to Axler's book on measure theory?

Comment: @Quasar I'm not really familiar with Axler's book, but *Understanding Analysis* isn't very comprehensive. If you don't want to use Rudin (which no sane person should in my opinion), I suggest having a look at Terence Tao's two-volume *Analysis* to fill any gaps in your knowledge (I've certainly quite liked it). He even goes into the basics of measure theory in the second volume.

Comment: @ChubbyChef, thanks that is helpful. I'm enjoying learning analysis, by taking LaTeX notes (though these are very verbose). 
http://www.mathsummaries.com/Proofs_in_Real_Analysis.pdf

Comment: You can always dive in to a math book you're not ready for and then backtrack to fill in gaps in knowledge as necessary. I'd guess that Axler's book is definitely worth spending some time on, even if you ultimately choose to focus more on a different book.

Comment: i was about to say this: i suggest, like aduh, A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory by Rosenthal. i further suggest that probability with martingales by david williams be NOT used as a main text, but i suggest williams' book as a supplement.

Comment: My book *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis* (the electronic version is legally available for free at https://measure.axler.net/) should be accessible after you finish Abbott's book. Also, the website for my book includes a free *Supplement* that reviews some of the background material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory* by Rosenthal. The first five chapters, in particular, seem like exactly what you're looking for: a very gentle introduction to the basics of measure theory with an eye toward probability.

Comment: i was about to say this: i suggest, like aduh, A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory by Rosenthal. i further suggest that probability with martingales by david williams be NOT used as a main text, but i suggest williams' book as a supplement.